# How do I install Wine without internet connection?

Tags: wireless, software-installation, wine

I'm trying to install a wireless internet receiver so I can browse the web but it requires an installation disc. The problem is, the install file is an .exe file. I've been trying to install Wine through the tar.bz2 and the "README" tells me to do something with the "wineinstall" file in "tools". It doesn't actually tell me WHAT to do with it...

I've tried copying the "wineinstall"'s contents into command but it just closes when I paste it.

Help?

Comment: You can download the .deb from https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=wine&field.series_filter=&field.status_filter=published&batch=75&memo=75&start=75 (choose the one for your system, utopic is 14.10, precise is 12.04) If you want an earlier version check page 1.

Comment: The Windows exe file is probably not the correct way to install the driver. Tell us about the device and we may be able to help. Open a terminal and, if a PCI device, run and post: lspci -nn | grep 0280. If USB, then: lsusb Thanks.